# My Flask Application keeps stopping on Google Cloud Compute Engine after sometime

Tags: flask, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-app-engine-python

I have deployed a Flask App on Google Cloud Compute Engine as well as Google App Engine.
The app is running continuously on Google App Engine (24*7). But on Compute Engine Virtual machine the app runs for some time and then it stops (like after an hour). It gives me this error.

[image]

**I have to go to the Virtual machine and re-run the app in order to access it.**

The app is running on port 5000 in the Virtual machine in the Compute Engine. And I have the external IP. I am able to access the app on the browser using EXTERNAP_IP/5000 . I am very new to Google Cloud. I don't even know what to ask. It would be great if you can point me what I might be missing.

Comment: What type of VM are you using? This sounds like a [Preemptible Vm](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/faq#what_are_preemptible_vm_instances_and_how_are_preemptible_instances_different_than_normal_instances)

Comment: debian-9-stretch-v20200805 is the image type @TasosV

Comment: I was referring to the availability policy parameter on your VM's configuration, but that's okay. It would be nice to check your logs and let us know what are the messages you are receiving on Stackdriver logging while your app goes down.

Comment: how do you launch you web server on Compute Engine ?